# How Can i change window 7 32 bit operating system to 64 bit without reinstall..?

Tags: windows, operating-system

Is there any possible way to change the **32 bit windows 7 operating system to 64 bit** without reinstall...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No. Everything needs to be re-installed.

Comment: I would say only answer, not short answer